# DDE: C# NDde DdeClient.Request frequently returns "No Data"?

Tags: c#, dde

Using NDde project (http://ndde.codeplex.com/) from C# to read data from DDE server.  Frequently, the DdeClient method Request() will return "#No Data".  Calling the exact same method again and the data will be returned.  Why does this happen?

How to solve it? Note I tried putting the Request() call in a loop such that if no data is returned then it will retry for a given number of times.  However, looping even 10 times the data will still sometimes come back "No Data".  However, if I set a breakpoint, the data will almost always be returned the second time.  I'm guessing this is because there is a longer time between requests.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the Advise functionality instead of Request.  To do that subscribe to the Advise event?

```
client.Advise += OnAdvise;
```

where OnAdvise is the event handler method.  Then start the advise loop.

```
client.StartAdvise("myitem", 1, true, 60000);
```

Now when the data becomes available, the Advise event will fire and you will get your data from the EventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say there is probably a timing issue with the DDE server. Did you try temporal spacing between the `Request` operations?